# How to flatten an array and get rid of null?

Tags: java, arrays, object, arraylist, null

I am trying to take an arbitrarily deep-nested array and flatten the array, as well as get rid of any null objects in the array.

For example I want to be able to input a nested array like 
`[1, 5, [[6, 4], 91, 12, null, [[null]]], -2]`
and return a one-dimensional array without any null values. How would I go about solving this?

I provided my solution below, but I keep getting an

> I cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer error.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] numbers = {null, {4, 5, 6},{3, 1, 10}, {4, 2, 9}, null, null};
    flatten(numbers);
}

public static ArrayList<Integer> flatten(Object[] nestedNumbers) {
    if (nestedNumbers == null) return null;
    ArrayList<Integer> flattenedNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Object element : nestedNumbers) {
        if (element != null) {
            flattenedNumbers.add((Integer)element);
        } 
    }
    return flattenedNumbers;
 }
```

Comment: **What** compilation error?

Comment: I edited it to a more specific error

Comment: Does the array have 2 dimensions only?

Comment: I want a solution that can take any arbitrary nested array, whether it be 2, or 3 dimensions, etc. The array I am testing it on is a 2-dimensional array.

Comment: You passed as `Object[] nestedNumbers` `int[][] numbers`. This means that your array is array of objects which internally store `int[]` arrays. So when you iterate over them with `for (Object element : nestedNumbers) {` that `Object element` represents `int[]` not `int`. You could improve your codes in few ways but choice would depend on what you really want to achieve/how you want to use this method. So provide some examples of input, explain which one is valid and which one is not, and explain what results you expect.

Comment: I edited it to add an example of what I want to achieve.

Comment: Do you require from method to accept only nested array of `int` elements? Of are `double` `long` or some mix of numerical types also allowed?

Comment: A mix of numerical types are allowed.

Comment: In that case what type should be used here to return their values? If we cast `1.5` into int we will get `1`. Try to think of such scenarios so you wouldn't need to rewrite your code (and others their answers).

Comment: This is in fact very complicated to do in a generic manner, and supporting primitive types. Restricting to 2 or 3 dimensions, on the other hand, is quite feasible.

Comment: What is a solution for just int elements? The problem I am having is, how can I convert a deep-nested array of let's say type "int" into a flat array, while also getting rid of the nulls.

Comment: What about `ArrayUtils.addAll()`? Probably the simplest answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A possible solution using the [Stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/) introduced in Java 8 is the following:

```
public static int[] flatten(Object[] array) {
    return Arrays.stream(array)
                 .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                 .flatMapToInt(a -> {
                    if (a instanceof Object[]) return Arrays.stream(flatten((Object[]) a));
                    return Arrays.stream((int[]) a);
                 })
                 .toArray();
}
```

The first point to consider is that an `int[]` is not an `Object[]`. So, this method accepts a `Object[]` to represent that it can be given any type of integer array with at least 2 dimensions, i.e. `int[][]`, up to any number of dimensions. It filters out null elements, with the [`Objects::nonNull`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#nonNull-java.lang.Object-) predicate.

Then the magic happens: the `Stream<Object>`, returned by `Arrays.stream(array)`, is flat mapped to an `IntStream`: if the elements inside it are `Object[]`, then it means that we still have more than 2 dimensions, and the method is recursively calling itself. On the other hand, if we have an instance of `int[]`, then we can just replace it with a Stream of that.

Example calling code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][][] numbers = {null, {{4}, {5}, {6,1}},{{3,2}, {1}, {10}}, {{4,1}, {2,3}, {9,8}}, null, null};
    int[] flat = flatten(numbers);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(flat));
}
```

Of course, this method doesn't accept `int[]`, which would be the case where is nothing to flatten (and nothing to filter since `int` can't be `null`).

Answer (score 2):

One of *simplest* (but not necessary fastest) solution could be to:

- generate string which will represent your array (`Arrays.deepToString` can be helpful here) like

  ```
  "[null, [4, 5, 6], [3, 1, 10], [4, 2, 9], null, null]"
  ```
- remove from it characters like `[` `]` `,`
- split on spaces
- iterate over received array to

  - filter all "null" strings
  - convert non-null strings to numeric type of your choice and add it to result list.

In short your solution could look like (I am assuming you are allowed to use Java 8)

```
public static List<Integer> flatten(Object[] nestedNumbers) {
    String text = Arrays.deepToString(nestedNumbers);
    System.out.println(text);
    return Stream.of(text.replaceAll("\\[|\\]|,", "").split("\\s+"))
        .filter(s->!s.equals("null"))
        .map(Integer::parseInt)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

---

In case you want to split floating point numbers and your locale is also using `,` as decimal mark `1,25` you would need to decide which `,` we should remove and which `,` is part of number and should stay. For such case solution could be removing `,` which has space after it (but we don't want to remove that space because we need it in `split`). Since `replaceAll` is using regex we can use look-ahead `(?=...)` mechanism which will allow us to test part after current match, but not include that tested part in match.

So we would need to `replaceAll("\\[|\\]|,(?=\\s)","")` which will ensure that removed `,` must have space after it, but will not remove that space.

Comment: Ah, nice hack (hadn't thought of that one :D)

Comment: Yeah, main part of solution is done by `deepToString` so no need to reinvent anything :) But creating string will require some time and space so I prefer your solution in real world (you already got ++).